# blank Row in TableView JavaFx APP

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

i am trying to use tableview in my javafx app but it's giving me blank rows in tableview.....
Here is sample output :

[image: sampleoutput]

Here is the code for model class:

```
public class Pizza {
    private final SimpleStringProperty pname;
    private final SimpleStringProperty pflavour;
    private final SimpleStringProperty psize;
    private final SimpleDoubleProperty pprice;
    public Pizza(String name, String flavour, String size, Double price) {
        super();
        this.pname = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.pflavour = new SimpleStringProperty( flavour);
        this.psize = new SimpleStringProperty(size);
        this.pprice = new SimpleDoubleProperty(price);
    }
    public String getName() {
        return pname.get();
    }
    public String getFlavour() {
        return pflavour.get();
    }
    public String getSize() {
        return psize.get();
    }
    public Double getPrice() {
        return pprice.get();
    }

}
```

Here is the code for controller class :

```
        @FXML
        private TableView<Pizza> pizzatable;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<Pizza,String> pname;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<Pizza,String> pflavour;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<Pizza,String> psize;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<Pizza,Double> pprice;
        ObservableList<Pizza> pizzalist;
```

Here is the code for method that i call to fetch data from databse:

```
public void fetchpizza() throws SQLException{
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        sql = "select * from items where itype = 'Pizza'";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        pname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Pizza,String>("pname"));
        pflavour.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Pizza,String>("pflavour"));
        psize.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Pizza,String>("psize"));
        pprice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Pizza,Double>("pprice"));
        pizzalist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        while(rs.next()){
            pizzalist.add(new Pizza(rs.getString("oname"),rs.getString("flavour"),rs.getString("size"),rs.getDouble("price")));
            pizzatable.setItems(pizzalist);
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
    }
```

Comment: First are you sure your itype = 'Pizza'  is well written?, second does this pizzalist.add("toto","tata","titi", "waou") work?

Comment: You need not set the `items` ot the `TableView` in every iteration of the loop. Doing this once should be sufficient.

Comment: have this problem fixed? i have same problem with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `String`s corresponding to the getters or property getters as argument for the `PropertyValueFactory` constructor.

E.g. one of the following methods of the items would be used to retrieve the value/property, if you pass `"name"` as parameter to the constructor of `PropertyValueFactory<Pizza, String>`:

- `nameProperty()` (should return `StringProperty`). This allows to observe changes in the value without having to call `TableView.refresh()`.
- `getName()` (should return `String`)

You pass the name of the fields however. Since the method names do not march the required pattern, the `TableCell`s remain empty.